# Properly firing JavaScript on Different tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having difficulty trying my make my javascript fire in all of the necessary places in my project. Before I get into the problem, let me give you a little background of the project.

I made a JSFiddle which is a very elementary, but an accurate mock up of my current website. The idea is that when you click the black boxes, the info associated with that box appears in the grey "info" box.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dQUk/27/

The problem is that the only clickable area in the the black boxes is the area surrounding the p tag (https://i.stack.imgur.com/204Qj.jpg)

Is there a way to make the javascript fire when any region of the black box is clicked? I have tried adding a p exception in the JavaScript, but it did not work....

```
$("#block-buttons").on("click", "div", ***"p",*** function (clickEvent) {
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!!

Comment: What area isn't clickable? I can click anywhere and it works.

Comment: The area highlighted on the imgur link. What browser are you using. That my be my problem. I have ie10 (work computer, I would never use it lol)

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Maybe IE is picky ;)

Comment: enclose your div in <a href=#"></a> , so that users can know that div is clickable

Comment: @CodeRunner: Don't do that. Anchor tags link somewhere. Use CSS to make `cusor: pointer` on the clickable div.

Answer (score 5):

The issue isn't the clickable area, it's the logic in the event handler.

Here is a working version

http://jsfiddle.net/5dQUk/36/

I just changed the target line to

```
var target = $(this).data("target");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the anwser. It comes from your way of detecting clicks on the black boxes. I forked your fiddle there :

http://jsfiddle.net/agv8F/1/

The problem came from your line :

`var target = $(clickEvent.target).data("target");`

Basically, when you clicked on the `<p>` area, the `$(clickEvent.target)` pointed to that said `<p>` tag, which doesn't have any `data-target` attribute.

What I changed is that I directly selected the `div` element, using `$(this)` afterwards, and could retrieve the data accordingly. I hope this helps.